# How to add missing data selector in "Create new entity" rules action?

Tags: 7, rules, notifications, message-subscribe

I have created an activity log using the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module. It is about [Statuses](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses) module (for which I'm using the DEV version). When someone comments on a status update, the activity is logged, but it should be logged for the status update owner and not the current user.

Currently, when I create the rules action "Create new entity" in the rules setup, the only replacement pattern available in the data selector for "User for which to log" is 'site:current-user'. Here I want 'status:status-sender' and not 'site:current-user'. The owner of the status update must receive the notification and not the user who commented.

Message export

```
{
  "name" : "status_comments",
  "description" : "Status comments",
  "argument_keys" : [ "@status_comments_user" ],
  "argument" : [],
  "category" : "message_type",
  "data" : {
    "token options" : { "clear" : 0 },
    "purge" : { "override" : 0, "enabled" : 0, "quota" : "", "days" : "" }
  },
  "language" : "",
  "arguments" : null,
  "message_text" : { "und" : [
      {
        "value" : "@status_comments_user commented on your status",
        "format" : "plain_text",
        "safe_value" : "@status_comments_user commented on your status"
      }
    ]
  },
  "rdf_mapping" : []
}
```

Rules export

```
{ "rules_posted_statuses_comment" : {
    "LABEL" : "Posted a statuses comment",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "statuses" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "fbss_comments_rules", "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "fbss_comments_save" : [] },
    "IF" : [ { "NOT fbss_comments_rules_on_own" : { "comment" : [ "comment" ] } } ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "message",
            "param_type" : "status_comments",
            "param_user" : [ "site:current-user" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "entity-created:arguments:status-comments-user" ],
          "value" : "[comment:commenter]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Note: This is strange because I have another message type with the event "user saves a status" and in its rules action, it shows all replacement patterns for statuses in data selectors**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're starting to hit the limits of the most recent (beta2) release of the Statuses module. Have a look at this variation of a custom rule, which is included in [Comment nr 13 of issue nr 1693620](https://www.drupal.org/node/1693620#comment-6886978):

```
{ "rules_user_commented_on_status" : {
    "LABEL" : "User commented on a status",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "TAGS" : [ "Statuses" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "fbss_rules", "rules", "fbss_comments_rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "fbss_comments_save" ],
    "DO" : [
      { "fbss_rules_load_action" : {
          "USING" : { "sid" : [ "comment:sid" ] },
          "PROVIDE" : { "status_loaded" : { "status_loaded" : "Loaded status" } }
        }
      },
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : "[status-loaded:sender:mail]",
          "subject" : "[comment:commenter:name] commented on your status",
          "message" : "Hi [status-loaded:sender:name],\r\n\r\n[comment:commenter:name] commented on your status [status-loaded:message-formatted]\r\n\r\n\r\nRegards,\r\n[site:name]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Even though this is not really the rule you're looking for, pay attention to the "to" field in the eMail being constructed. That to-field uses token `...sender:mail`, which is close to the uid (I believe) of the "sender".

That very same comment in that issue also includes a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/rules-integration-issue-1693620-13.patch) (which I believe is committed to the current DEV version), clearly an improvement (not a bug fix ...) because it makes extra data available for subsequent Rules processing. This patch appears to be a prereq for the above rule to work: I tried to import that rule in a site using the beta2 version, but that import failed (and "I" do not want to use a DEV version, even using beta-versions is exceptional to me).

I suggest you either try to apply that patch in your current setup, or switch to the DEV version of that module. After you do so, continue with these extra steps:

- Try to import that same eMail example, so that you have a sample rule that is close to what you'll need.
- Expand your own rule, to also add such "load action" and then check if you have a similar token like that `[status-loaded:sender:mail]`, which in your case should become something like `[status-loaded:sender:name]` or `[status-loaded:sender:uid]`.

If you get that import of the eMail sample to work, then I would assume (have not tested it myself and leave that to you) that this comination of your rule with part of the eMail sample here is what you're looking for:

```
{ "rules_posted_statuses_comment" : {
"LABEL" : "Posted a statuses comment",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"TAGS" : [ "statuses" ],
"REQUIRES" : [ "fbss_comments_rules", "fbss_rules", "rules" ],
"ON" : { "fbss_comments_save" : [] },
"IF" : [ { "NOT fbss_comments_rules_on_own" : { "comment" : [ "comment" ] } } ],
"DO" : [
  { "fbss_rules_load_action" : {
      "USING" : { "sid" : [ "comment:sid" ] },
      "PROVIDE" : { "status_loaded" : { "status_loaded" : "Loaded status" } }
    }
  },
  { "entity_query" : {
      "USING" : {
        "type" : "user",
        "property" : "uid",
        "value" : [ "status-loaded:sender" ],
        "limit" : "1"
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "entity_fetched" : "Fetched entity" } }
    }
  },
  { "entity_create" : {
      "USING" : {
        "type" : "message",
        "param_type" : "status_comments",
        "param_user" : [ "entity-fetched:0" ]
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
    }
  },
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "entity-created:arguments:status-comments-user" ],
      "value" : "[comment:commenter]"
    }
  }
]
```

}
}

Note the `status-loaded:sender` in the above rule! Which should be a token you can use because of the very first Rules Action added now.

**Disclaimer**: I have NOT (repeat NOT) tested this last rule (since I never use DEV versions of a module). Though chances are that by copy/pasting relevant parts of your original (exported) rule and the (exported) eMail rule it does work as it should.

**Note**: I'm about sure that the integrity check you got (when trying to import my updated rule, as you wrote in a comment to this answer) is because "status-loaded:sender" is not returned as a "User entity". While the Message module wants/expects the "param_user" to be a "User entity".

You might be able to "convert" that "status-loaded:sender", by adding a Rules Action "Fetch entity by property", whereas you would use "status-loaded:sender" as the property to do so. The entity type to be fetched should be, for sure, a "user" entity (not a "message"!). This Rules Action should be inserted after the first "`fbss_rules_load_action`".

The result of performing that extra Rules Action is then an actual "user entity" (a real entity), and that is what you might then use for that "param_user" (which should avoid the integrity check error).